# Using SIM800C send post request, get "ERROR" when setting URL(short) parameter

Tags: c

I'm using sim800c to send post request, everything look good, but it happaned that i got “ERROR” responed from modem when setting "URL", the url i set is short like"http://procedure.xxxxtech.com:1234".Then it will lanch recived event in module, but get data from modem error.Actually,the postdata was not sent.Once this happaned, it wont fix until remove power and plug in agian,then set url(i mean cold reboot fix, hot reboot is no use).

It is a situation that is very difficult to reproduce, and only appeared twice by now.

i changed url, it work well, but changed back, it still failed.

i check the log of http server, no data shown in log about request.

i tried empty url, it do return "ERROR",and lanch recived event and failed just like my problem .But my problem echo the cmd i wrote in, that is url is right.

i tried error url which is just no response url, everything is ok.

About the url format, first time it appeared i used format like `http://entry.xxx.com/entry/ObtainRouteUrl`, and i changed it to `http://procedure.xxxxtech.com:1234`, it sent request successfully, then i changee it back, failed still.The second time it appeared , the format we used is `http://procedure.xxxxtech.com:1234`, so it seems has nothing to do with the url format.

```
AT+HTTPTERM
modem recv: AT+HTTPTERM
ERROR

AT+SAPBR=1,1
modem recv: AT+SAPBR=1,1

modem recv: 
OK

AT+HTTPINIT
modem recv: AT+HTTPINITOK

AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
modem recv: AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1OK

AT+HTTPPARA="REDIR",1
modem recv: AT+HTTPPARA="REDIR",1OK

AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://procedure.xxxxtech.com:1234"
modem recv: AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://procedure.xxxxtech.com:1234"
ERROR

AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json;charset=utf-8"

modem recv: AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json;charset=utf-8"
OK

AT+HTTPPARA="TIMEOUT",50
modem recv: AT+HTTPPARA="TIMEOUT",50
OK

AT+HTTPSSL=0
modem recv: AT+HTTPSSL=0
OK

AT+HTTPDATA=199,100000
modem recv: AT+HTTPDATA=199,100000
DOWNLOAD
post data: {"appId":"306382023969210368","ctVsn":"13.1.18","devTp":"AT-XL3","did":"865209034329046","osTp":"RTOS","osVsn":"Nucleus","ts":"2004-01-01 08:02:31.000 +0800","sig":"08D74DEA267707685A883D40003FE2F8"}
modem recv: 
OK

AT+HTTPACTION=1
modem recv: AT+HTTPACTION=1
ERROR

AT+HTTPREAD
modem recv: AT+HTTPREAD
+HTTPREAD: 199
{"appId":"306382023969210368","ctVsn":"13.1.18","devTp":"AT-XL3","did":"865209034329046","osTp":"RTOS","osVsn":"Nucleus","ts":"2004-01-01 08:02:31.000 +0800","sig":"08D74DEA267707685A883D40003FE2F8"}
OK

AT+HTTPTERM
modem recv: AT+HTTPTERM
OK

AT+SAPBR=0,1
modem recv: AT+SAPBR=0,1
modem recv: 
OK
```

http should work just right and send data , but didn't send data and hard to fix.

Answer (score 0):

AT-command manual describes "URL" in the following way:

```
"http://'server'/'path':'tcpPort'"
```

In your command, the 'path' is missing:

```
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://procedure.xxxxtech.com:1234"
```

Could you try to add path of your default page to the url. For example:

```
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://procedure.xxxxtech.com/index.html:1234"
```

Comment: hello,thank u for answering, i did find the AT-command format requirement on its reference just as you have mentioned. But  it is really a situation that is very difficult to reproduce, and i just used `http://procedure.xxxxtech.com:1234` before and now, it works with no problem. Actually,though this problem only happaned twice by now, it can be dangerous because we never use post request so frequently before and it cost a lot.At the first time it happaned, the url i used is `http://entry.xxxx.com/entry/obtainRouteUrl`.I will supplement my description，thx.